# Android: How to getBundle Key

Tags: android, variables, arguments, bundle

I cant figure how to get a Bundled Key to the conditional method &/the Toast message below.

Any help will be greatly appreciated for my learning experience.  Thnx.

```
public class ListViewFragment extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener {
    private final String KEY_ADPTR_ID = "KEY_ADPTR_ID";
}

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState):

        Bundle args = this.getArguments();
        args.getString(KEY_ADPTR_ID);
        . . .
    }
. . .
    private void showData(String json) throws JSONException {

        String adptrID = this.getBundle(KEY_ADPTR_ID);//<-HOW DO I ACCOMPLISH THIS CORRECTLY!!??

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), adptrID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (adptrID == "3") {
           . . .
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written in onActivityCreated is correct if you're passing the KEY_ADPTR_ID in the fragment's arguments

```
Bundle args = this.getArguments();
String keyAdaptrId = args.getString(KEY_ADPTR_ID);
```

Comment: Thnx.  I was just trying that again and it worked correctly.  I think I had a type-o when I first ran it and I thought my method of getting the key was incorrect.